# blackberry - launch wifi setup from application

Tags: blackberry, wifi

Is it possible to open "manage connections" from app?
My application need to use WLAN. So when it starts i check if wifi is on and connection to network. If it's not connected I would like to open "manage connections" and let user connect. Is it possible?
I was looking at ApplicationManager class but didn't figure out if it's possible. 
I uses OS5 api.

Thanks for replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to launch "manage connections" from within your app.

```
    try {                  
         ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager().launch("net_rim_bb_manage_connections");
    } catch (ApplicationManagerException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can find the name of this and similar apps by watching the console while you launch it from the dashboard. Example console output:

```
Starting net_rim_bb_manage_connections
Started net_rim_bb_manage_connections(198)
```

Comment: @Ray Vahey: Does it vary from OS to OS (or even from device model to device model)?

Comment: From what I've seen, RIM's application names are conistent across OS's and devices. At least from 4.5 to 6.